# How to get current Active Directory user in ASP.NET when IIS is running under a service account

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, active-directory

I need to get the name and email address of the user currently logged into Active Directory from a website that is using a service account as the application pool identity in IIS.  I've tried the following two methods but they return the name of the service account, not the actual user logged into the network (which makes sense).

System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

should provide the identity of the authenticated user